# Add margin when any child element does not have a class

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a menu in CSS which looks like:

```
<li id="menuTask" class="menuEntry line">
    <div>
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img alt="Task" src="Resources/Icons/Task.png" />
        </div>
         <div class="menuItem">Task</div>
     </div>
 </li>
<li id="menuTask2" class="menuEntry line">
    <div class="subMenuHolder>
        <div class="imageHolder">
            <img alt="Task" src="Resources/Icons/Task.png" />
        </div>
         <div class="menuItem">Task</div>
     </div>
 </li>
```

You'll notice that every menuitem is wrapped inside a LI element. In some cases the DIV under the li element has a class `subMenuHolder`.

Now I would like to add some padding on the LI element, but only if the child div element does not contain the class `subMenuHolder`.

Is something like that possible with plain CSS selectors?

I was thinking about using the :not selector, but I don't quite find it.

Comment: I know but this was some quick copy-pasting. My id's are really different :)
I've changed it in the original question to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: In current CSS you cannot influence a parent element's appearance based on the child. You have to solve this in a different way.

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. jQuery to the rescue :-)

Comment: Maybe you only have to rethink the structure a bit.

Comment: @Complexity if js can be used for the solution, please edit the question and add the proper tags